# Null Reference Exception when Clicking a button in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have created a web application for online testing.

The website is running perfectly fine on my local machine but giving an error on remote server.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            arrSessionALL_questions = Session["arrALL_questions"] as int[];
            arrSessionQuestion_ID = Session["arrayOfQuestionID"] as int[];
            arrSessionCorrectAns = Session["arrayOfCorrectAns"] as string[];
            arrSessionCorrectAnsMarks = Session["arrayOfCorrectAnsMarks"] as int[];
            arrSessionAns_ID = Session["arrayOfAnsID"] as string[];
            arrSessionAttempted_ID = Session["arrayOfAttemptedID"] as int[];
            arrSessionMarkQuestion_ID = Session["arrMarkQuestion_ID"] as int[];
            arrSessionLeft_ID = Session["arrayOfLeftID"] as int[];
            arrSessionTotalMarks = Session["arrTotalMarks"] as int[];
}

protected void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    PanelTimer.Visible = true;
    PanelQuestNum.Visible = false;

    try
    {       

    if (arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] != 0)
    {


        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"]) < arrSessionALL_questions.Length)
        {
            //Session["QuestionCounter"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"]) + 1;
            LabelStudentName.Text = arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])].ToString();
            correctAns = arrSessionCorrectAns[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])].ToString();
            correctMarks = Convert.ToInt32(arrSessionCorrectAnsMarks[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])]);
            PanelQ.Visible = true;
            ButtonSTART.Visible = false;
            ButtonMark.Visible = true;


            PanelTimer.Visible = true;
            PanelQuestNum.Visible = false;


            if (RadioButtonListAns.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {

                arrAns_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] = RadioButtonListAns.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Session["arrayOfAnsID"] = arrAns_ID;
                arrSessionAns_ID = Session["arrayOfAnsID"] as string[];


                if (arrSessionAns_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] == correctAns)
                {
                    studentMarks = correctMarks;
                    attempt_correct_wrong = "correct";
                }
                else
                {
                    studentMarks = 0;
                    attempt_correct_wrong = "wrong";
                }


                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Student_Analysis where((date='" + date + "' AND username='" + username + "') AND (PaperName='" + papername + "' AND QuestionNumber='" + arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] + "'))", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds, "Student_Analysis");
                int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    con.Close();

                    con1.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Student_Analysis set studentAns='" + arrSessionAns_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] + "',studentMarks='" + studentMarks + "',attemp_correct_wrong='" + attempt_correct_wrong + "' where((date='" + date + "' AND username='" + username + "') AND (PaperName='" + papername + "' AND QuestionNumber='" + arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] + "'))", con1);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con1.Close();
                }
                else
                {

                    con.Close();

                    con1.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student_Analysis values('" + date + "','" + studentId.ToString() + "','" + studentName + "','" + username.ToString() + "','" + papername + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(LabelStudentName.Text) + "','" + arrSessionAns_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] + "','" + correctAns + "','" + studentMarks + "','" + correctMarks + "','" + attempt_correct_wrong + "')", con1);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con1.Close();
                }

}

            else
            {
                arrAns_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] = "NULL";
                Session["arrayOfAnsID"] = arrAns_ID;
                arrSessionAns_ID = Session["arrayOfAnsID"] as string[];


                studentMarks = 0;
                attempt_correct_wrong = "Not attempted";



                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Student_Analysis where((date='" + date + "' AND username='" + username + "') AND (PaperName='" + papername + "' AND QuestionNumber='" + arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] + "'))", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds, "Student_Analysis");
                int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    con.Close();

                    con1.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Student_Analysis set studentAns='" + "NULL" + "',studentMarks='" + studentMarks + "',attemp_correct_wrong='" + attempt_correct_wrong + "' where((date='" + date + "' AND username='" + username + "') AND (PaperName='" + papername + "' AND QuestionNumber='" + arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] + "'))", con1);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con1.Close();
                }
                else
                {

                    con.Close();

                    con1.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student_Analysis values('" + date + "','" + studentId.ToString() + "','" + studentName + "','" + username.ToString() + "','" + papername + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(LabelStudentName.Text) + "','" + "NULL" + "','" + correctAns + "','" + studentMarks + "','" + correctMarks + "','" + attempt_correct_wrong + "')", con1);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con1.Close();
                }
            }


            if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"]) < arrSessionALL_questions.Length - 1)
            {
                Session["QuestionCounter"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"]) + 1;
                loadQuestion();
                ButtonMark.Visible = true;


                //Checking if question has been marked
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from StudentMarkedQuestions where((date='" + date + "' AND username='" + username + "') AND (PaperName='" + papername + "' AND markedQuestionNumber='" + arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] + "'))", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds, "Student_Analysis");
                int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    ButtonMark.Visible = false;
                    ButtonUnMark.Visible = true;

}

                else
                {
                    ButtonMark.Visible = true;
                    ButtonUnMark.Visible = false;
                }
                //Checking if question has been marked
            }
            else
            {
                LabelStudentName.Text = "End of questions!!";
                PanelQ.Visible = true;
                ButtonSTART.Visible = false;
                ButtonFinish.Visible = true;
                ButtonNext.Visible = true;
                ButtonPrevious.Visible = true;

            }


        }
        else
        {
            LabelStudentName.Text = "End of questions!!";
            PanelQ.Visible = true;
            ButtonSTART.Visible = false;

            ButtonFinish.Visible = true;
            ButtonMark.Visible = false;
            ButtonPrevious.Visible = false;
            ButtonNext.Visible = false;
            ButtonUnMark.Visible = false;

        }
    }


    }   //try ends     
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

       Response.Write(ex.Message);          
    }
}

public void loadQuestion()
{
    if (arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] != 0)
    {


        con1.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from QuestionInsert where(QuestionNum='" + arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] + "')", con1);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        adp1.Fill(ds1);
        LabelQuestion.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"]) + 1) + ".  " + ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
        con1.Close();


        RadioButtonListAns.Items.Clear();
        con2.Open();
        string strQuery = "select * from QuestionInsert where(QuestionNum='" + arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] + "')";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, con2);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con2.Close();
        RadioButtonListAns.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(dt.Rows[0]["Option1"].ToString(), dt.Rows[0]["Option1"].ToString()));
        RadioButtonListAns.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(dt.Rows[0]["Option2"].ToString(), dt.Rows[0]["Option2"].ToString()));
        RadioButtonListAns.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem(dt.Rows[0]["Option3"].ToString(), dt.Rows[0]["Option3"].ToString()));
        RadioButtonListAns.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem(dt.Rows[0]["Option4"].ToString(), dt.Rows[0]["Option4"].ToString()));
        RadioButtonListAns.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem(dt.Rows[0]["Option5"].ToString(), dt.Rows[0]["Option5"].ToString()));



        //Selects radiobutton if answer found in database
        con3.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Student_Analysis where((date='" + date + "' AND username='" + username + "') AND (PaperName='" + papername + "' AND QuestionNumber='" + arrSessionQuestion_ID[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionCounter"])] + "'))", con3);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "Student_Analysis");
        int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            con3.Close();

            string ans = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
            if (RadioButtonListAns.Items.FindByText(ans) != null)
            {
                RadioButtonListAns.Items.FindByText(ans).Selected = true;
            }
        }
        con3.Close();
        //Selects radiobutton if answer found in database
    }

}
```

This is the code that I have applied, I have given the code from Page Load and ButtonNext_Click() event.

While starting the test, it loads two questions but then if you will click on next button again, it is giving me this error:

```
 [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
       StudentTestingPage.ButtonNext_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +2018
       System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553178
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

I tried everything that I know and searched about everything on internet but still unable to fix it.
I have checked all the variables and arrays that can be set to null, the code is running fine on local machine.
I have used SQL Server as database.

Comment: We need the full parameters to solve the problem in the question itself. With a site we have to log into, when something changes, this question becomes useless for future visitors.

Comment: @Hanumendra - Just checked it gives null reference exception on the ButtonNext_Click() method

Comment: Also: The text of the error should be in the question, not as an image, but as the actual text. We also need the code that this error references. Specifically, the code that is the `StudentTestingPage.ButtonNext` method.

Comment: Holy cow that got closed quickly. I was in the middle of writing an answer. While the question has issues, this is clearly someone lacking a few basic debugging skills - maybe they don't know how to ask what they're looking for yet. Oh well.

Comment: @hanumendra: The clue is in the stack trace. You are calling a method or getting/setting a property on something that is `null` in the handler for `ButtonNext`.

Look at your `ButtonNext_Click()` method and try to see what objects might be null.

Comment: Thanks Bibhu! But it is working fine on my local machine

Comment: @NeilBarnwell The problem is that this question isn't formulated nearly well enough to be useful to anyone else, and the OP hasn't put the information into the question that we need to solve their problem. Sure, we could use our [psychic debugging powers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/21/399688.aspx), but that's not what Stack Overflow is meant for.

Comment: @Hanumendra You need to look at your code and try to work it out in your head. Otherwise, put some code in to test for nulls at runtime, and deploy that version to tell you what objects are null. Can you post the content of the `ButtonNext_Click` method?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker But it's not even had a chance, yet. Why don't we ask him for more info and get him to improve it before just closing it. Harsh, man. Real harsh.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell Its called [on hold] for a reason, if it improves it will be reopened

Comment: @NeilBarnwell Now that he's included the code, want to give your answer a shot?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker My answer went in a comment and actually even with that code it's about as helpful as I can be. There are a lot of "improvements" that could be made but ultimately it's a guessing-game. Ugh. You try to stand up for someone a bit then this is what you end up with. Oh well.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell Yea. Any 'answer' I gave would just be a review of the code here.  Without a line number that matches up with the code we see, it's hard to figure out where the NRE is, and even then, 90% of an answer would just include improvements to the code.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker which is what I've ended up doing. The point being though, that better code would make this problem easier to find. I think that makes it relevant, but I appreciate that might violate the rules so I'll leave it to you.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell I never (and will never) delete an answer that makes a good faith attempt to address a problem a user has, even if that answer doesn't directly answer the question.  I like your answer, and I'm glad you have the time help out the OP on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the stack trace. You are calling a method or getting/setting a property on something that is `null` in the handler for `ButtonNext`.

Look at your `ButtonNext_Click()` method and try to see what objects might be null.

If you can't replicate locally, then consider building a DEBUG build and deploying that. That should give you the actual line number throwing the exception in the stack trace.

### However

This code has many serious issues. If you work on improving the overall quality of the code, simple things like `NullReferenceException` become easier to locate and resolve.

1. **Method length** You need to cut your frankly MASSIVE `ButtonNext_Click()` method into many, small (maybe even less than 10 lines) descriptively-named methods. If you have [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) [learn how to use it](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Extract_Method.html). If you don't, buy it and [learn how to use it](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Extract_Method.html). However even [Visual Studio has "Extract Method" these days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s21cwxk.aspx) - [USE IT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yez2fsct%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). In particular the contents of `if/else` blocks might be good candidates.
2. **[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)** You are being very naughty - concatenating SQL strings is a BAD IDEA. Instead, [parameterise your SQL strings](http://johnhforrest.com/2010/10/parameterized-sql-queries-in-c/). Better still, use Entity Framework (comes free in the .NET framework) or something like Dapper.
3. Don't use `"NULL"`. Use `null` and note the important difference.

One last thing - you shouldn't see the Yellow Screen of Death, really. You should always turn it off in production in your `web.config`:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, Thanks a lot, I have fixed the issue with your help.
You are really a nice human being

Comment: You're very welcome. Care to share exactly what the issue was, and why it was different in your production site than it was locally?